# Selecting all textnodes in table with XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

This is a a page from an open databse about food:

http://www.dabas.com/ProductSheet/Details.ashx/121308

Im trying to get some info from this page using XPath.
The table I'm interested in is the one called: *Näringsvärde*.
I want to get all the textnodes inside "Näringsvärde" saved into a string.

This is the relevant portion of the code linked above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body>
...
<table class="width100" style="page-break-inside: avoid">
    <caption>
        Produktinformation
            <img src="../../images/ProductSheet/draw-triangle3.png" id="toggleProduktinformation"
                 class="imgCaptionOn" />
    </caption>
    <tbody id="tbodyProduktinformation">
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">
                Ursprungsland:
            </td>
            <td>
Sverige            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="tableHover" class="width100 marginTop30 bgTable">
<tr class="nohover">

<td class="tdLeft48 padding0">
    <table id="nutritiveTabel" class="leftTable" style="page-break-inside: avoid">
        <caption>
            Näringsvärde
                <img src="../../images/ProductSheet/draw-triangle3.png" id="toggleNutritiveValues"
                    class="imgCaptionOn" />
        </caption>
        <tbody id="tbodyNutritiveValues">
            <tr id="divNutritiveValues">
                <td class="padding">
                    <table class="noBorder width100">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col1">
                                    Tillagningsstatus:
                                </td>
                                <td>Tillagad</td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    &amp;amp;nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ...
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
...
</html>
```

I tried using something like this so far, but it didn't work:

```
public List<string> GetNaring(string xid) {         
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(xid);
    var xpath = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody";
    var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
    return links.Select(n => n.InnerText).ToList();
```

}

But this only gives back *null*, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression:

```
/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody
```

does not match any nodes.

Since you have an unique string you can match, you should use it. Searching for that string in the source code, you will find:

```
...
<td class="tdLeft48 padding0">
    <table id="nutritiveTabel" class="leftTable" style="page-break-inside: avoid">
        <caption>
            Näringsvärde
                <img src="../../images/ProductSheet/draw-triangle3.png" id="toggleNutritiveValues"
                    class="imgCaptionOn" />
        </caption>
        <tbody id="tbodyNutritiveValues">
            <tr id="divNutritiveValues">
...
```

The string is a child of the `caption` element inside the table you want. You have to get the *string value* of that element, trim the extra spaces and use the result to compare to "Näringsvärde". You can select the correct `table` using this expression:

```
//table[normalize-space(caption/text())='Näringsvärde']
```

Once you have the correct table, you can navigate inside it and select the nodes you want, or you can get the *string-value* which is a concatenation of all the descendant text nodes:

```
//table[normalize-space(caption/text())='Näringsvärde']//td
```

This will return all `td` nodes, which is where the text is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and the lesson! It worked perfectly and i will sure revisit this question the next time!

Comment: Im not sure why but this code gives back all information twice.., do you have any idea what that could be? Maybe something wrong elswhere?

Comment: If the information is not duplicated in the original file, the problem is not in the XPath expression.